# Disable "Proceed to Checkout" button on cart page magento 2

Tags: checkout, cart, shopping-cart, magento-2.2.5

In my custom module I have to check some conditions and have to disable "Proceed to Checkout" button from the Cart page.

I know it's coming from

```
magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage\link.phtml
```

I can override this but I have to also override block for this. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module or if you have a design template create `view -> frontend -> templates -> onepage -> link.phtml` and inside just put:

```
<?php

?>
<?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>

<?php endif?>
```

This should just not create the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code, here I have rewritten the template file in my custom module.
**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Anshu_Custom::onepage/link.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/templates/onepage/link.phtml**

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button"
            data-role="proceed-to-checkout"
            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Proceed to Checkout') ?>"
            data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout":{"checkoutUrl":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCheckoutUrl() ?>"}}'
            class="action primary checkout<?= ($block->isDisabled()) ? ' disabled' : '' ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isDisabled()):?>disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?>>
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span>
    </button>
<?php endif?>
```

I have just copied the code from original core `link.phtml` file, you can modify it according to your requirement.

Comment: I am doing exact same thing that you mentioned above, added a code in custom block to check customer group data and disable button based on that check. In my case it disabled the button for all the customers including Guest. I tried cacheable=false in layout xml and it didn't fix it either. What kind of caching issue is it since the button is disabled even after `bin/magento cache:flush`?

Comment: @cnu The code is just for over ridding the template file, you need to apply the condition according to your requirement.

Comment: Right, I have the condition and it's working but the button disappears even when data is not there for the condition, so trying to understand if it's a caching or some other problem.

Comment: @cnu Doesn't seems to be cache issue, I am assuming it will be a condition issue. Kindly check your condition.

Comment: found the issue. It was a typo in one of the variable names in custom Block, hence the button was missing for every customer.

Comment: Hi @AnshuMishra i have tried your code but no luck

Comment: @NIPPU What issue you are facing? and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AnshuMishra I am unable to override proceed to checkout button from thmy custom module i have tried in different ways https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295718/magento2-hide-proceed-to-checkout-button-on-cart-page/295719#295719

Answer (score -1):

Override the helper function **canOnepageCheckout**. To achieve this you need to override the following class

> Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data

Create your own module and add the following code to your **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data" type="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data" />
</config>
```

And update your logic to the below function:

```
public function canOnepageCheckout()
{
    return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```