# Magento2 hide proceed to checkout button on cart page

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

1. Need to hide `proceed to checkout` button on the cart page when session variable set
2. Need to add one more button `PROCEED TO APPROVAL` below the `Proceed to checkout` button on the cart page.

Followed different approached mentioned here but no luck.

**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<!-- first approach failed -->
<!--<body>
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block class="Ken\Bestseller\Block\Onepage\MyLink" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Ken_Bestseller::onepage/mylink.phtml">
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>-->

<!-- second  approach failed -->
<!-- <body>
  <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Ken_Bestseller::onepage/mylink.phtml" />
  </referenceContainer>
</body> -->

<!-- 3rd  approach failed -->
  <!--<body>
       <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Ken_Bestseller::onepage/mylink.phtml"/>
   </body> -->

<!-- added custom button -->
  <body>
      <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods" >
            <block class="Ken\Bestseller\Block\Onepage\MyLink" name="custom.template.kenisum" after="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" template="Ken_Bestseller::onepage/mylink.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this once ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Ken_Bestseller::onepage/mylink.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this works for you then.

Comment: sure @Kishan Savaliya will update you shortly

Comment: Thanks, @krishan which is working fine

Comment: You're welcome buddy ;)

Comment: @krishan savaliya can u advise on this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295908/magento-2-pass-php-session-variable-to-minicart-mixin-js

Comment: Yes, sure give me some time. I'll check this @NIPPU

Comment: Hello @kishan can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/magento-2-how-to-fetch-post-method-for-punchout

Comment: @NIPPU, I'm not clear there can you please elaborate more there ? So I can check.

Comment: Hi @kishan can you please help me on this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302603/magento-2-override-add-wishlist-controller

Comment: Hi @Kishan can you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319106/magento2-restrict-cc-number-in-the-form-fields