# Magento 2 pass php session variable to minicart & hide proceed to checkout

Tags: magento2, cart, javascript, mini-cart, mixins

I would like to pass a PHP session variable flag to mini cart-mixin.js dynamically. I followed the below steps mentioned here using the Config Provider concept I am able to pass variable to only cart page hence for remaining pages the condition is not satisfied facing an issue can any once advise?

**Note**: I would like to hide proceed to checkout button on cart page.

app/code/Test/Demo/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
    '*': {
    'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html':
    'Test_Demo/template/minicart/content.html'
    }
},
config: {
    mixins: {
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart': {
    'Test_Demo/js/view/minicart-mixin': true
    }
  }
}

};
```

app/code/Test/Demo/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart-mixin.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isButtonEnable: function () {
            console.log("isButtonEnable calling");

            /*You can add your condition here based on your requirements.*/
            //console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);
            if(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData){
                return true; //hide button
            }else {
                return false;  //show button
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

app/code/Test/Demo/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="additional_provider" xsi:type="object">Test\Demo\Model\AdditionalConfigProvider</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Test/Demo/Model/AdditionalConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\Demo\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;

class AdditionalConfigProvider implements \Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SessionManager
    */
    private $coreSession;

    /**
     * @param SessionManager $sessionManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        SessionManager $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
    }

   public function getConfig()
   {
      //$this->coreSession->setVIErequestData(1);  // Set Session Data
      //$this->coreSession->unsVIErequestData();   // Unset Session Data
      //$this->coreSession->getVIErequestData();

      if($this->coreSession->getVIErequestData()){  
            $output['session_VIEUserData'] = true;
        } else {
            $output['session_VIEUserData'] = false;
       }       
       return $output;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you also tried, but i am not able to access window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData in my js file,Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass your PHP SESSION variable data in your `JS` then please follow below steps :

1. Create `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

2. Create `DefaultConfigProvider.php` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;

class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
    /**
     * @var SessionManager
    */
    private $coreSession;

    /**
     * @param SessionManager $sessionManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        SessionManager $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $output = parent::getConfig();
        if($this->coreSession->getVIErequestData()){
            $output['session_VIEUserData'] = true;
        }else{
            $output['session_VIEUserData'] = false;
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Now run below command once

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you can use below line in your `JS` file to get PHP SESSION variable data there

```
console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);
```

- If you want to get session data for all pages in your mixin js file then you can do below thing in your JS file

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isButtonEnable: function () {
            console.log("isButtonEnable calling");

            var baseUrl = window.BASE_URL;
            var redirectUrl = baseUrl + 'frontName/index/index/';
            var sessionData;

            $.ajax({
                url: redirectUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    if(data.success){
                        sessionData = data.sessionData;
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });

            /*You can add your condition here based on your requirements.*/
            //console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);
            //You can use 'sessionData' in your condition
            if(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData){
                return true; //hide button
            }else {
                return false;  //show button
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Now you need to create one controller action, because we have added one ajax call here

So create your frontend router and create one controller file

Content for controller file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $coreSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SessionManager $sessionManager
        ) {
        $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $sessionData = ($this->coreSession->getVIErequestData()) ? true : false;
        return $this->resultFactory
        ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
        ->setData([
            'success' => true,
            'sessionData' => $sessionData
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can follow this module as well. [Download](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-magehelper-magento2)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Let me know if this works for you then

Comment: sure @krishan I am checking now will let you know. one small query console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);
is this will load on all pages (or) only on cart & checkout page?

Comment: All pages means checkout and cart page ? or you want this on any other pages as well ?

Comment: other pages as well.

Comment: Give me few mins I'll update my answer

Comment: ok @krishn let me explain what i am facing an issue here i.e when we use this config provider those concept is applicable for cart & checkout not for other pages.  Hence minicart proceed to checkout button is not hiding properly when the session data is set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101164/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-nippu).

Comment: sure @kishan i will try with the ajax calling will let  you know

Comment: Let me know if you need any help here then

Comment: Hi @kishan i have updated my post here can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2-controller

Comment: Hi @kishan can u suggest me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297391/magento-2-3-1-ce-is-not-showing-the-requested-qty-is-not-an-available-after-disa

Comment: hi @kishan can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298310/redirect-to-magento2-website

Comment: Hi @kishan do u have idea on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299393/magento-2-create-custom-product-link-type-example-consumable-grid-with-products

Comment: Hi @kishan how are you, Happy new year and need your suggestion and help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300095/magento-2-how-to-import-custom-linkproducts

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311165/m1-how-to-fetch-wishlist-data-in-csv-format can u help me on this

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to hide proceed to checkout button if the session variable to set.
which will affect the cart page proceed to checkout buttons at minicar at section & bottom of the page.

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data">
       <plugin name="canOnepageCheckoutData" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\ProceedToCheckoutButton" disabled="false"/>
   </type>  
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/ProceedToCheckoutButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;
/**
 * Class ProceedToCheckoutButton
 * @package Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin
 */
class ProceedToCheckoutButton
{

     /**
     * @var SessionManager
    */
    private $coreSession;

     /**
     * @param SessionManager $sessionManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        SessionManager $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterCanOnepageCheckout(\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $subject, $result)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/magento4.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);        
        $logger->info("CanOnepageCheckout plugin has been calling");

        $this->coreSession->setVIErequestData(123);//Set
        //$this->coreSession->unsVIErequestData(); //unset
        if($result){
         if($this->coreSession->getVIErequestData()) {
            return false;
         }
         return $result;
        }

    }
}
```

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile php bin/magento
>
> setup:static-content:deploy -f