# Redirect to Magento2 website with session id

Tags: magento2, controllers, session, post

We have a small requirement like a **punchout payload concept**. The user will redirect to Magento 2 website from 3rd party with the `session_id`. We want to capture that `session_id` and implement our logic. Could you please let me know in how many ways, we can achieve it? what is the best way to implement.

Comment: It looks like SID in Magento: https://yourdomain.abc?SID=12321

Comment: Yes. like that only

Comment: I think it's only way to implement `session_id`

Comment: ok please let me know how to implement in m2?