# Magento 2 would like to override configurable.js method form custom module

Tags: magento2, admin, configurable-product, products, jquery

Here I would like to override the configurable.js there is a method **_fillSelect**  The below method is working for preselecting the first children. I would like to override from my custom module what are the steps need to follow here.

```
_fillSelect: function (element) {
    var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
        options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
        prevConfig,
        index = 1,
        allowedProducts,
        i,
        j;

    this._clearSelect(element);
    element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
    element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
    prevConfig = false;

    if (element.prevSetting) {
        prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
    }

    if (options) {
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            allowedProducts = [];
            if (prevConfig) {
                for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                    // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                    if (prevConfig.config &&
                        prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                        prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                        allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);
            }

            if (allowedProducts.length > 0) {
                options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);
                if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                    element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                }

                element.options[index].config = options[i];    
                index++;
            }
            // Code added to select option
            if (i == 0) {
                this.options.values[attributeId] = options[i].id;
            }   
        }
        //Code added to check if configurations are set in url and resets them if needed 
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1) {this._parseQueryParams(window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1));}
    }

},
```

Comment: https://github.com/magepal/magento2-link-product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** ***Override configurable js without mixin***

Create **requirejs-config.js** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

with below content:

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
      'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable':'Vendor_Module/js/configurable'
    }
  }
};
```

Now create **configurable.js** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

and copy all the content from **configurable.js** under

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

and modify the required things.

Now flush the cache and run static content deploy.

**Method 2:** ***Extend configurable js through mixin***

**Step 1:**

Create **requirejs-config.js** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

with below content:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/configurable': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 2:**

Create **configurable.js** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

with below content:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (configurable) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', $['mage']['configurable'], {
            _fillSelect: function (element) {
                    console.log('extend working through mixin');
                    var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
                    options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
                    prevConfig,
                    index = 1,
                    allowedProducts,
                    i,
                    j,
                    finalPrice = parseFloat(this.options.spConfig.prices.finalPrice.amount),
                    optionFinalPrice,
                    optionPriceDiff,
                    optionPrices = this.options.spConfig.optionPrices,
                    allowedProductMinPrice;

                this._clearSelect(element);
                element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
                element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
                prevConfig = false;

                if (element.prevSetting) {
                    prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
                }

                if (options) {
                    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        allowedProducts = [];
                        optionPriceDiff = 0;

                        /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                        if (prevConfig) {
                            for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                                // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                                if (prevConfig.config &&
                                    prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                                    prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                                    allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);

                            if (typeof allowedProducts[0] !== 'undefined' &&
                                typeof optionPrices[allowedProducts[0]] !== 'undefined') {
                                allowedProductMinPrice = this._getAllowedProductWithMinPrice(allowedProducts);
                                optionFinalPrice = parseFloat(optionPrices[allowedProductMinPrice].finalPrice.amount);
                                optionPriceDiff = optionFinalPrice - finalPrice;

                                if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {
                                    options[i].label = options[i].label + ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(
                                        optionPriceDiff,
                                        this.options.priceFormat,
                                        true);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (allowedProducts.length > 0) {
                            options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                            element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                            if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                                element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].price);
                            }

                            element.options[index].config = options[i];
                            index++;
                        }

                        /* eslint-enable max-depth */
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return $['mage']['configurable'];
    };
});
```

You can update your code according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @sukumar if I would like to override only _fillSelect method how do we do?

Comment: You can try Magento mixin concept.

Comment: can u guide me how to do it?

Comment: Hi @sukumar can u please assist me only a particular method on how to override?

Comment: @NagarajuK Please check the updated code with Method 2.

Comment: Thanks @sukumar I will make the changes locally. One more suggestion required from your end i.e i would like to do first items should be preselect

Comment: Sukumar but first items preselection is not working.

Comment: This is only for extend configurable.js. Can you check any modification to this file working fine or not. Its working on magento 2.3.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102607/discussion-between-nagaraju-k-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: do u have any idea how to add a custom tab on PDP page for configurable products only?

Comment: small help @sukumar how do we club 2 mixens in a single file

Comment: In the same way I have done on requirejs-config.js

Comment: Thanks for your support @sukumar can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300095/magento-2-how-to-override-member-variable

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are using a custom module names "Company_MyModule".

**step 1)** create ***requirejs-config.js*** under *app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/*

File : **app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
 var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'Company_MyModule/js/configurable-custom'
        }
    }    
};
```

**step 2)** create ***configurable-custom.js*** under *app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js*

File: **app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-custom.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
], function($){

    $.widget('mycustom.configurable', $.mage.configurable, {

            _fillSelect: function (element) {
             var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
                options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
                prevConfig,
                index = 1,
                allowedProducts,
                i,
                j;

            this._clearSelect(element);
            element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
            element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
            prevConfig = false;

            if (element.prevSetting) {
                prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
            }

            if (options) {
                for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    allowedProducts = [];

                    /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                    if (prevConfig) {
                        for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                            // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                            if (prevConfig.config &&
                                prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                                prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                                allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);
                    }

                    if (allowedProducts.length > 0) {
                        options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                        element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                        if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                            element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                        }

                        element.options[index].config = options[i];
                        index++;
                    }

                    /* eslint-enable max-depth */
                }
            }
        },        


    });

    return $.mycustom.configurable;
});
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: once again i will veirfy and let you know

Comment: requirejs-config.js in this file is there anything we are missing?