# Magento 2 how to import custom link type products

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport, catalog-product

We have created custom link types like consumable, recommended, etc..like cross-sells, upsells, related.
Now we would like to implement the import functionality for these custom types. We have written below code on vendor file `(Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php)` so that while import custom link types are working as expected.

> File Path: Vendor/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php

```
 /**
     * Links attribute name-to-link type ID.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_linkNameToId = [
        '_related_' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED,
        '_crosssell_' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CROSSSELL,
        '_upsell_' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_UPSELL,
        '_required_' => \StackExchange\RequiredProduct\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_REQUIRED,
        '_consumable_' => \StackExchange\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CONSUMABLE,
        '_recommended_' => \StackExchange\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_RECOMMENDED,
        '_optional_language_arts_' => \StackExchange\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_OPTIONAL_LANGUAGE_ARTS,
        '_fivedays_also_includes_' => \StackExchange\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_FIVEDAYS_ALSO_INCLUDES
    ];



/**
         * Map between import file fields and system fields/attributes.
         *
         * @var array
         */
    protected $_fieldsMap = [ ......
                                           .......                                         
            '_required_sku' => 'required_skus',
            '_consumable_sku' => 'consumable_skus',
            '_recommended_sku' => 'recommended_skus',
            '_optional_language_arts_sku' => 'optional_language_arts_skus',
            '_fivedays_also_includes_sku' => 'fivedays_also_includes_skus'
        ];
```

Now I would like to override and add my data from my custom module. Can anyone guide and provide me the steps, please.

I have followed below link but no luck

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-link-product

**My CSV format looks like this:**

[image]

Comment: Related question: How can those links be exported? magepal/magento2-link-product does not include that, right?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution for this I have the override `Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php` file

1. Created di.xml in the following file path `app/code/StackExchange/AdditionalItems/etc/di.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product" type="StackExchange\AdditionalItems\Model\Import\Product"/>
   </config>
   ```
2. Created file app/code/StackExchange/AdditionalItems/Model/Import/Product.php

   ```
   <?php
     namespace StackExchange\AdditionalItems\Model\Import;
    class Product extends \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product
    {


   const COL_MEDIA_IMAGE = '_media_image';

   const COL_STORE = '_store';

   const COL_TYPE = 'product_type';

   const COL_ATTR_SET = '_attribute_set';

   const COL_PRODUCT_WEBSITES = '_product_websites';    

   protected $_linkNameToId = [
       '_related_' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED,
       '_crosssell_' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CROSSSELL,
       '_upsell_' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_UPSELL,
       '_required_' => \Kensium\RequiredProduct\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_REQUIRED,
       '_consumable_' => \Kensium\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CONSUMABLE,
       '_recommended_' => \Kensium\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_RECOMMENDED,
       '_optional_language_arts_' => \Kensium\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_OPTIONAL_LANGUAGE_ARTS,
       '_fivedays_also_includes_' => \Kensium\AdditionalItems\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_FIVEDAYS_ALSO_INCLUDES
   ];

   protected $_fieldsMap = [
       'image' => 'base_image',
       'image_label' => "base_image_label",
       'thumbnail' => 'thumbnail_image',
       'thumbnail_label' => 'thumbnail_image_label',
       self::COL_MEDIA_IMAGE => 'additional_images',
       '_media_image_label' => 'additional_image_labels',
       '_media_is_disabled' => 'hide_from_product_page',
       self::COL_STORE => 'store_view_code',
       self::COL_ATTR_SET => 'attribute_set_code',
       self::COL_TYPE => 'product_type',
       self::COL_PRODUCT_WEBSITES => 'product_websites',
       'status' => 'product_online',
       'news_from_date' => 'new_from_date',
       'news_to_date' => 'new_to_date',
       'options_container' => 'display_product_options_in',
       'minimal_price' => 'map_price',
       'msrp' => 'msrp_price',
       'msrp_enabled' => 'map_enabled',
       'special_from_date' => 'special_price_from_date',
       'special_to_date' => 'special_price_to_date',
       'min_qty' => 'out_of_stock_qty',
       'backorders' => 'allow_backorders',
       'min_sale_qty' => 'min_cart_qty',
       'max_sale_qty' => 'max_cart_qty',
       'notify_stock_qty' => 'notify_on_stock_below',
       '_related_sku' => 'related_skus',
       '_related_position' => 'related_position',
       '_crosssell_sku' => 'crosssell_skus',
       '_crosssell_position' => 'crosssell_position',
       '_upsell_sku' => 'upsell_skus',
       '_upsell_position' => 'upsell_position',
       'meta_keyword' => 'meta_keywords',
       '_required_sku' => 'required_skus',
       '_consumable_sku' => 'consumable_skus',
       '_recommended_sku' => 'recommended_skus',
       '_optional_language_arts_sku' => 'optional_language_arts_skus',
       '_fivedays_also_includes_sku' => 'fivedays_also_includes_skus'
   ];    


    }
   ```
3. Added sequence from my custom module

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="StackExchange_AdditionalItems" setup_version="1.2.1">
          <sequence>                   
             <module name="Magento_CatalogImportExport"/>
          </sequence>
   </module>
   ```
4. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: In upcoming Magento 2.4 it should work via di.xml - not need anymore to overwrite the Product.php

Answer (score 1):

As with Magento 2.4 and higher, you can fix this with use of dependency injection and a plugin. This approach is cleaner and more upgrade proof than a class rewrite.

Let's say the code of the custom link type is `custom_type` and you have a module Vendor_Module, you will need this code:

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\LinkProcessor">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="linkNameToId" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- Const should be id of link type as added in db table catalog_product_link_type -->
                <item name="_custom_type_" xsi:type="const">Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CUSTOM_TYPE</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Type\AbstractType">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="vendorModuleAbstractType" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Import\Product\Type\AbstractTypePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Import/Product/Type/AbstractTypePlugin:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Import\Product\Type;

use Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Type\AbstractType;

class AbstractTypePlugin
{
    /**
     * @param AbstractType $subject
     * @param string[]     $result
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function afterGetCustomFieldsMapping(AbstractType $subject, array $result): array
    {
        $result['_custom_type_sku'] = 'custom_type_skus';

        return $result;
    }
}
```

After cache flush you can import custom link type with product import in admin using a csv file like this:

```
"sku","custom_type_skus"
"product_sku","linked_sku_1,linked_sku_2"
```

Comment: This works fine for me on Magento 2.4.5 as well.